# Is there any problem in DataGenerator for 3D data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried to use DataGenerator for 3D data set. But I got some error.

[image: Error message]

class DataFeedGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

```
def __init__(self,x1,x2,y,batch_size=32, dim=(44,52,52,1), n_channels=1, n_classes=1, shuffle=True, name="Training"):
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.Y = y
    self.X1 = x1
    self.X2 = x2
    self.currentX1 = None
    self.currentX2 = None
    self.currentY = None
    self.batch_index = 0
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.name = name

def __len__(self):
    n = math.ceil(self.X1.shape[0] / self.batch_size)
    print(self.name, "__len__", n)
    return n


def __getitem__(self,index):
    self.currentX1 = self.X1[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    self.currentX2 = self.X2[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    self.currentY = self.Y[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

    return [self.currentX1, self.currentX2], self.currentY
```

Comment: Here is generate code. trainingGen = DataFeedGenerator(X1_train, X2_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, name="Training Gen"). The dimension of X1_train and X2_train is (15000, 44,52,52,1).

Answer (score 0):

Does the error only occurs for the 208th batch?
Considering your shapes and batch_size, the total number of batches should be 15000/32=468, since you have 245 as total number it means that you give a batch_size of 61? is that correct?
Also,

```py
self.currentX1 = None
self.currentX2 = None
self.currentY = None
...
self.currentX1 = self.X1[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
self.currentX2 = self.X2[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
self.currentY = self.Y[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
return [self.currentX1, self.currentX2], self.currentY
```

Why are you using class attribute, you could only use local variable current_x1, current_x2...
I would also write the __len__ as:

```py
def __len__(self):
    return math.ceil(len(self.X1) / self.batch_size)
```